# Download blob from gcp storage bucket with python flask

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a GCP bucket with some pdf files.
I am able to download the files from bucket with python(flask) on local host using below code -

```
storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json("ebillaae7f0224519.json")
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("bill_storage1")
blob = bucket.blob(file_name)
blob.download_to_filename("file1.pdf")
```

But when deployed on GCP(app engine) i get this error "line 1282, in download_to_filename with open(filename, "wb") as file_obj: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'file1.pdf'"
Then i modified code to -

```
storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json("ebillaae7f0224519.json")
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("bill_storage1")
blob = bucket.blob(file_name)
blob.download_to_filename("/tmp/file1.pdf")
```

This works after deployment but i cant download the files from bucket to local folder through my app, how to do that?

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 2):

You cannot write or make modifications within Google App Engine's file system post deployment. You can only read files within the app. That is why certain storage solutions such as Cloud Storage or any database is a recommended way to store files or data.

[Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard) is serverless. It can scale up quickly because it is simply spinning up instances based from the container image built from your source code and pre-built runtime. Once the container image is built during deployment, you can no longer write/edit its contents. You will have to redeploy to make changes.

One exception is the directory called `/tmp` where you can store temporary files. It's because this directory is mounted in the instance's RAM. Storing temporary data consumes RAM. Therefore, when the instance is deleted, files in the `/tmp` directory are deleted as well.

You may check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-temp-files?hl=en) for additional information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tempfile.gettempdir()` function to get the tmp directory according to your runtime environment

For example

```
import tempfile

storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json("ebillaae7f0224519.json")
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("bill_storage1")
blob = bucket.blob(file_name)
blob.download_to_filename("{}/file1.pdf".format(tempfile.gettempdir()))
```

Locally, the file will be download in your OS default temporary directory.

Comment: Hey thanks, but the file format is not pdf and i wish to download the file as attachment and open it on api call, any idea?

Comment: It wasn't the purpose of your question. I simply took your code example and solve the temp dir issue. Anyway, can you detail what do you want to do? What is a "download as attachment", and "open on API call"? Are y ou talking about frontend? backend? What do you want to achieve?